# Find $n\in\mathbb N$ so that: $\sqrt{1+5^n+6^n+11^n}\in\mathbb N$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

Find $n\in\mathbb N$ so that: $\sqrt{1+5^n+6^n+11^n}\in\mathbb N$
My attempt led me to have $\quad n=2k+1:\quad k\in\mathbb N$
The expression under square root is odd, so the square root's value is also odd.
I assumed $\sqrt{1+5^n+6^n+11^n}=2a+1:\quad a\in\mathbb N \Rightarrow$
$5^n+6^n+11^n=(2a+1)^2-1 \Rightarrow 5^n+6^n+11^n=4a(a+1)$
Then the expression on the left must be divisible by 8
$5^n\equiv 5\pmod 8$ if $n$ is odd, $5^n\equiv 1\pmod 8$ if $n$ is even.
$6^n\equiv 0\pmod 8$ if $n\ge3$.
$11^n\equiv 3\pmod 8$ if $n$ is odd, $11^n\equiv 1\pmod 8$ if $n$ is even.
Then $n$ must be odd and $\ge3$ for the expression to be divisible by 8.
I'm stuck here, would anyone give a hand please?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is never an integer. If $n\in\mathbb N$, then$$1+5^n+6^n+11^n=1+5^n+(5+1)^n+(10+1)^n\equiv3\pmod5,$$but every perfect square is congruent to $0$, $1$, or $4\pmod5$.

Comment: Many thanks, you're right. It must be a wrong question but I failed to prove that.

Comment: don't you feel the number $0$ glaring at you angrily.

Comment: For some people, $0 \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: For me, $0$ doesn't belong to $\mathbb N$

Comment: @Wolfdale Neither for me.

Answer (score 2):

$1+5^n+6^n+11^n$ has the unit digit = $3$ for any $n$ and therefore cannot be a square

Indeed $11^n$ ends always with $1$,

$6^n$ ends with $6$,

$5^n$ ends with $5$ adding $1$ makes $13$ so we get the unit digit to be $3$ in any case

Hope this can be useful

Answer (score 1):

You could do also like this (for kids in elementary school).

$5^a$ always ends with $5$

$6^b$ always ends with $6$

$11^c$ always ends with $1$

So $1+5^a+6^b+11^c$ always end with 3 and there for it can not be perfect square.

Comment: What a coincidence! I wrote a proof that could be explained to almost everybody :)